# expo android standalone application: Prevent webview from redirect to an app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, deep-linking

Hi I have a webview inside the application which showing the authentication page using identity server. Once authenticated, it redirect to an application because of the redirect_uri.

Since webview already inside the application, i don't need the webview to call the redirect_uri to open up the new instance of the application.

Is there a way to intercept that? On android there is no support for react native webView onShouldStartLoadWithRequest. I could intercept when running in expo client and it will stop it form redirect to the app.

```
<WebView source={ { uri:loginSrc}} 
                ref={(ref) => {this.webView = ref; }}
                onNavigationStateChange={(e) => {
                  console.log("URL DATA Received");
                  console.log(e.url);
                  // if (e.url.startsWith("io.test.com://")) {
                  //   console.log("Go back to login")
                  //   e.goBack();
                  // }
                }}
                onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={
                  (data) => 
                  { 
                    //console.log("start request"); console.log(data);   
                    if (data.url.includes("#code")) {
                      this.setState({showLoginModal: false});
                      this._onExtractCode(data);
                      return false;
                    }
                    //console.log("end request");
                    return true;
                  }} ></WebView>
```

Or is there a way to prevent from deep linking to my application

```
http://uat-login.funny.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fnonce%3Dtesting%26client_id%3Dslon_hybrid%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%2520lynx%2520slon%2520offline_access%26redirect_uri%3Dio.test.com%253A%252F%252F%253Fcallback%253Dauthentication%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token
```

From above url, there is a redirect_uri which will open up a new instance of the app. Is there a way to cancel that request.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem? Having a similar issue myself!

Comment: I am using a hacky way ... I use a fixed redirect_uri e.g. http://blah blah and intersect  it my matching the uri. If there is matched, don't load the page and close the webview. I am using react-native-webview not the expo provided version.